# Absolute imports not working in jest tests (*.test.ts files)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, tsconfig, ts-jest

#### My Setup

I have a mono repo with jest tests in each package.

#### My code

Github repo [here](https://github.com/ziggy6792/cdk-monorepo-example-backend/tree/refactor/absolute-imports).

I have distilled my issue in an example package `lambda-a` which has the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "composite": true,
    "paths": {
      "@example/*": ["src/example/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

and the following `jest.config.js`

```
/* eslint-disable u/typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const base = require('../../jest.config.base.js');
const package = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  ...base,
  name: package.name,
  displayName: package.name,
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@example/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/example/$1',
    '^scr/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
};
```

#### My Problem

For my src `*.ts` files I can use relative, absolute and alias imports as shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oB2TArVb9Os94WQVvu6G6L7Y_OIXh5T1/view?usp=sharing)

For tests I am using `*.test.ts` files. My problem is that in my tests absolute and alias imports do not work as shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19g0Lh44vUfnFlalp2cjSQMUNTn6Ln9-z/view?usp=sharing)

Actually the tests run fine. My only issue is the linting errors and the fact that vs code doesn't give me any intelisense for the modules imported absolutely.

How can I get absolute and alias imports to work correctly in my tests?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think I found my issue.   

I was excluding `*.test.ts` in my base tsconfig.

I fixed it in my repo.

While I'm here if anyone has any feedback on my test setup as a whole. Any constructive criticism I would appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: Can you share your solution here? The repo seems dead